# Cleaning Data: Replacing Current Column Values with Values mapped in Dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now and have yet to come up with a solution.

My question is how do I change current column values in multiple columns based on the column name if criteria is met???

I have survey data which has been read in as a pandas csv dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("survey_data")
```

I have created a dictionary with column names and the values I want in each column if the current column value is equal to 1. Each column contains 1 or NaN. Basically any column within the data frame ending in '_SA' =5, '_A' =4, '_NO' =3, '_D' =2 and '_SD' stays as the current value 1. All of the 'NaN' values remain as is. This is the dictionary:

```
op_dict = {
 'op_dog_SA':5,
 'op_dog_A':4,
 'op_dog_NO':3,
 'op_dog_D':2,
 'op_dog_SD':1,
 'op_cat_SA':5,
 'op_cat_A':4,
 'op_cat_NO':3,
 'op_cat_D':2,
 'op_cat_SD':1,
 'op_fish_SA':5,
 'op_fish_A':4,
 'op_fish_NO':3,
 'op_fish_D':2,
 'op_fish__SD':1}
```

I have also created a list of the columns within the data frame I would like to be changed if the current column value = 1 called [op_cols]. Now I have been trying to use something like this that iterates through the values in those columns and replaces 1 with the mapped value in the dictionary:

```
for i in df[op_cols]:
    if i == 1:
        df[op_cols].apply(lambda x: op_dict.get(x,x))

df[op_cols]
```

It is not spitting out an error but it is not replacing the 1 values with the corresponding value from the dictionary. It remains as 1.

Any advice/suggestions on why this would not work or a more efficient way would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your question you want to replace all ones in a column with 1,2,3,4,5 depending on the column name?

I think all you need to do is iterate through your list and multiple by the value your dict returns:

```
for col in op_cols:
    df[col] = df[col]*op_dict[col]
```

This does what you describe and is far faster than replacing every value. NaNs will still be NaNs, you could handle those in the loop with fillna if you like too.

Comment: Thank you @tvashtar this worked perfectly, I did not think to loop through the column names. Appreciate the help on this